# Android apps and typical practices

Tags: android, admob

I have a paid app on Google Play, for which I obviously have a Google account (developer console) and a linked Wallet merchant account.

I want to release a free version of the app with ads. So I need to sign up with AdMod. I'm new to AdMob and I tried to find the recommended / typical practices on how to set this up, but couldn't find anything useful. Hence I have a few questions:

1. Shall I be using the same Google account which I have to set up AdMob, or a separate account will be better? What are the pros and cons?
2. How does AdMob payout works? Does it have to be linked to a Wallet account to make a transfer to my account or is it totally independent?

Thanks

Comment: Better to google for these stuffs

Answer (score 0):

It will be up to you if you choose the same account for Google Play Developer account, Wallet, and Admob. Admob does not pay to Wallet.

Admob has different forms of payment (depending on location): checks, electronic funds transfer (EFT), wire transfer, Western Union Quick Cash, EFT via Single Euro Payments Area (SEPA), and Rapida. Check [the Admob Help Center](https://support.google.com/admob/?hl=en#topic=2740022) for additional details